# Can I put a client's Google analytics code in an Iframe ad that's running on my site?

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, subdomain, reporting

Can I put a client's Google analytics code in an Iframe ad that's running on my site?

Newbie here... The client wants some tracking from the iframe ad. I've created the iframe and am hosting it on one of my servers in a utility directory/subdomain.

Are there any suggestions on doing this or things I should avoid regarding reporting since it's on my server?

Comment: Does anyone have any recommendations for this? Thanks!